# Preload view with theme

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

Currently, if I use preloaded view it has default navigation bar (without theme, which I apply using UIAppearance in AppDelegate).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
        InitialSlidingViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialSlidingViewController"];
        Person *person = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
              
        [vc view]; //Preloading view

        [self flipToViewController:vc fromItemAtIndexPath:indexPath withCompletion:NULL];
```

So, in transition I see default navbar:
[image]

and when transition is finished:
[image]

How to fix it? To see themed view in transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making navigation bar tint color the same as in theme.
If someone has better solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You may be want hide the navigation bar like this:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't fits me.